# Sending parent array state as props to child with "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined" in test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have parent component with state which includes array of objects. I am passing this array to Child component as props. In child component array is sorted then map and as result returns grandchild component. It is working but from test case i received error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

I am trying to check in child component if array exist and if array isn't undefined but i have the same error.

Parent component (airdropDB.airdrops is reference to array of objects from another file)

```
class ContentPanel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            airdrops: airdropDB.airdrops
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FiltrPanel />
                <AirdropPanel airdrops={this.state.airdrops}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
class AirdropPanel extends Component {
    render() {
        let airdropBlocks = this.props.airdrops.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.addDate - a.addDate;
        }).map((e, i) => {
            return (<Airdrop key={e.title + i}
                title={e.title}
                value={e.value}
                status={e.status}
                logo={e.logo} />)
        });
        return (
            <div data-testid="airdropPanel">
                {airdropBlocks}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Result is ok, i have proper and sorted airdropblocks but error from test case is alarming.

Test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import AirdropPanel from './AirdropPanel';
import { render } from 'react-testing-library';

describe('Airdrop Panel has', () => {
    it('Airdrop block inside', () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<AirdropPanel />);
        expect(getByText(/rozpocznij/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('multi airdrop blocks inside', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<AirdropPanel />);
        let moreThanOne = getByTestId("airdropPanel").childElementCount > 1;
        expect(moreThanOne).toBe(true);
    }); 
    it('airdropBlock dates from newer to older sort function works', () => {
        //Test zależny od bazy airdrop
        const { getByTestId } = render(<AirdropPanel />);
        const firstAirdropBLock = getByTestId("airdropPanel").firstChild;
        expect(firstAirdropBLock.firstChild.textContent).toBe("Crypto Circle X");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please upload your test file ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Error is in line with render functions in test cases.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `airdrops` props to AirdropPanel? e.g. <AirdropPanel airdrops={myAirdropsArray} /> in test file?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't know how i could miss that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.sort isn't run. That is most likely because this.props.airdrops is undefined

I don't know, but are you sure you shouldn't put something in your airdrops prop test?

```
const { getByText } = render(<AirdropPanel airdrops={??}/>);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't know how i could miss that. Thank you.